# Resize an array of images with OpenCV

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

I'm passing an array of images (IplImage**) to an object in C++ using OpenCV. I'm then trying to iterate over that array and resize them all to a fixed size (150x150)

I'm doing it this way:

```
for(int i = 0; i< this->numTrainingFaces; i++)
{
    IplImage* frame_copy = cvCreateImage( cvSize(150,150), this->faceImageArray[0]->depth, this->faceImageArray[0]->nChannels );
    cout << "Created image" << endl;
    cvResize(this->faceImageArray[i], frame_copy);
    cout << "Resized image" << endl;
    IplImage* grey_image = cvCreateImage( cvSize( frame_copy->width, frame_copy->height ), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
    cout << "Created grey image" << endl;
    cvCvtColor( frame_copy, grey_image, CV_RGB2GRAY );
    cout << "Converted image" << endl;
    this->faceImageArray[i] = grey_image;
    cvReleaseImage(&frame_copy);
    cvReleaseImage(&grey_image);
}
```

But I'm getting this output, and I'm not sure why:

```
Created image
Resized image
Created grey image
Converted image
Created image
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.type() == dst.type()) in cvResize, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.1.0/src/cv/cvimgwarp.cpp, line 3102
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /build/buildd/opencv-2.1.0/src/cv/cvimgwarp.cpp:3102: error: (-215) src.type() == dst.type() in function cvResize

Aborted
```

I'm basically just trying to replace the image in the array with the resized one in as few steps as possible.

Edit:

Revised my code as follows:

```
for(int i = 0; i< this->numTrainingFaces; i++)
{

    IplImage* frame_copy = cvCreateImage( cvSize(150,150), this->faceImageArray[i]->depth, this->faceImageArray[i]->nChannels );
    cvResize(this->faceImageArray[i], frame_copy);
    IplImage* grey_image = cvCreateImage( cvSize( frame_copy->width, frame_copy->height ), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
    cvCvtColor( frame_copy, grey_image, CV_RGB2GRAY );
    faceImageArray[i] = cvCreateImage( cvSize(grey_image->width, grey_image->height), grey_image->depth, grey_image->nChannels);
    cvCopy(grey_image,faceImageArray[i]);

    cvReleaseImage(&frame_copy);
    cvReleaseImage(&grey_image);
}
```

Then later on I'm performing some PCA, and get this output:

```
OpenCV Error: Null pointer (Null pointer to the written object) in cvWrite, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.1.0/src/cxcore/cxpersistence.cpp, line 4740
```

But I don't think my code has got to the point where I'm explicitly calling cvWrite, so it must be part of the library. I can give a full implementation if necessary - is there anything in my code that's going to create a null pointer?

My full source code is here: http://pastie.org/1447022 - a class is created, variables are set, then learn() is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Why do you use the C interface when you're using C++? The C++ interface is far friendlier and you wouldn't have had this problem with it.
- Your error is simple - your image differ in type, so you can't use the type from the first image for all images.

The line

```
IplImage* frame_copy = cvCreateImage( cvSize(150,150), this->faceImageArray[0]->depth, this->faceImageArray[0]->nChannels );
```

should be

```
IplImage* frame_copy = cvCreateImage( cvSize(150,150), this->faceImageArray[i]->depth, this->faceImageArray[i]->nChannels );
```

Also, `this->` is usually a no-op. `faceImageArray[0]->depth, faceImageArray[0]->nChannels` should suffice.

Comment: Argh, I don't know how I missed this - thank you. Now I'm getting an error about OpenCV Error: Input image depth is not supported by function (Unsupported format) in cvCalcEigenObjects.

Comment: Also regarding the C++ interface, I couldn't find as much documentation on using it so I stuck with the C one.

Comment: Think this is because I'm releasing the grey_image, and perhaps I need to do something else

Comment: changing the question makes it hard to answer properly. You have a memory leak in the code - you call createimage 3 times and releaseimage 2 times. You'd need to release `faceImageArray[i]` before assigning to it. From your code it isn't obvious where a null pointer would come from.

Comment: Ah apologies, I thought it'd save flooding with new questions. I'll have a tinker regarding that. Thanks :)

Comment: Just updated my main post with the full source code of this class if that's at all useful