# cvResize on a video frame

Tags: c++, c, opencv, scale

When trying to load an Image and copy a part of it or smooth, everything ok, but when I'm capturing video and try to copy a part of the frame, it becomes reverse and rotated on 180 degrees, does anybody knows why?

```
IplImage *scaled=cvCreateImage(sz,IPL_DEPTH_8U,3); 
capture = cvCaptureFromFile( "C:\\New York.avi" ); 
IplImage *frame = cvQueryFrame( capture ); 
cvResize(frame,scaled,CV_INTER_LINEAR); 
cvShowImage("123",scaled);
cvReleaseImage(&scaled);
```

Comment: IF you share your code, we might be able to help you. Otherwise, I suggest you use the **search** box for questions similar to yours.

Comment: Edit your question and insert the code there!

Comment: There's a bunch of similar questions around here. For instance: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4652874/176769

Comment: this link is not the same, cause with Image everything works good but with video no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to match the **depth** and **number of channels** of the destination image to make the *resize* operation work. Right now, you are assuming these values.

```
capture = cvCaptureFromFile("C:\\New York.avi"); 
IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame(capture); 
IplImage* scaled = cvCreateImage(sz, frame->depth, frame->nChannels); 

cvResize(frame, scaled, CV_INTER_LINEAR); 
cvShowImage("123", scaled);

cvWaitKey(0); // wait for a key press, and then

cvReleaseImage(&scaled);
```

I hope you are using a recent version of OpenCV.

**EDIT**:

On a comment below you stated that you are using **OpenCV b5a**. I just found [a message from 2006](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/40015?var=1) that mentions this version, which means you are using a jurassic release of OpenCV and that's probably the root of the problem.

There's a page that shows [how to use OpenCV with C++ Builder](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/C++Builder), but if you are having problems with that, I suggest you move to another compiler.

What you are observing is most likely a bug of this ancient release of OpenCV.

Comment: You know, this operation works with Image perfectly, but with Video makes reverse and rotation.

Comment: What version are you using? On which platform?

Comment: I'm using OpenCV_b5a in Borland 2009

Comment: I have no idea how old b5a is. Maybe that's the problem? How about the 2.3 version?

Comment: Which lib-files i should include in my project in 2.3 version?

Comment: cause it become bunch of errors like this "[BCC32 Error] complex(65): E2344 Earlier declaration of '_Ctraits<double>::_Cosh(double,double)'"

Comment: I updated the answer. Consider moving to another compiler, like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011238/opencv-2-3-c-visual-studio-2010/7014918#7014918

Comment: you right, in VS 2008 with 2.3 everything alright! but in Borland there is an error when i'm trying to use 2.3. thanks anyway!

Comment: Awesome. Click in the arrow near my answer to select it as the official answer to the question.